# force guest to login before access to detailed page product magento 2

Tags: magento2, login

I override  the controller Product/view.php

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Magenticians\AddModule\Controller\Rewrite\Product;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class View extends \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\View
     */
    protected $viewHelper;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\ForwardFactory
     */
    protected $resultForwardFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;


    protected $_categoryFactory;
    protected $_productFactory;

    Protected $customerSession;


    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\View $viewHelper
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\ForwardFactory $resultForwardFactory
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\View $viewHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\ForwardFactory $resultForwardFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory
    )
    {
        $this->viewHelper = $viewHelper;
        $this->resultForwardFactory = $resultForwardFactory;
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;

        $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
        $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;

        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Redirect if product failed to load
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect|\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Forward
     */
    protected function noProductRedirect()
    {
        $store = $this->getRequest()->getQuery('store');
        if (isset($store) && !$this->getResponse()->isRedirect()) {
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('');
        } elseif (!$this->getResponse()->isRedirect()) {
            $resultForward = $this->resultForwardFactory->create();
            $resultForward->forward('noroute');
            return $resultForward;
        }
    }


    /**
     * Product view action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Forward|\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect
     */
    public function execute()
    {



            // Get initial data from request
            $categoryId = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('category', false);
            $productId = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
            $specifyOptions = $this->getRequest()->getParam('options');


                if (!$this->_request->getParam('___from_store')
                    && $this->_request->isPost()
                    && $this->_request->getParam(self::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED)) {

                    $product = $this->_initProduct();
                    $cats = $product->getCategoryIds(); // All Categories of $product you will get in array format eg. array(catid 1, catid 2, catid 3


                    if (!$product) {
                        return $this->noProductRedirect();
                    }else if ($product && (!($this->customerSession->isLoggedin())) && ($cats == 8)) {
                        die ("ggggggggggggggggg44444444444");


                        $this->customerSession->setAfterAuthUrl($this->_url->getCurrentUrl());
                        $this->customerSession->authenticate();
                        die ("ggggggggggggggggg");

                    }


                    if ($specifyOptions) {
                        $notice = $product->getTypeInstance()->getSpecifyOptionMessage();
                        $this->messageManager->addNotice($notice);
                    }
                    if ($this->getRequest()->isAjax()) {
                        $this->getResponse()->representJson(
                            $this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data::class)->jsonEncode([
                                'backUrl' => $this->_redirect->getRedirectUrl()
                            ])
                        );
                        return;
                    }

                    $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
                    $resultRedirect->setRefererOrBaseUrl();
                    return $resultRedirect;


                }


            // Prepare helper and params
            $params = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
            $params->setCategoryId($categoryId);
            $params->setSpecifyOptions($specifyOptions);

            // Render page
            try {
                $page = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
                $this->viewHelper->prepareAndRender($page, $productId, $this, $params);
                return $page;
            } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e) {
                return $this->noProductRedirect();
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->_objectManager->get(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::class)->critical($e);
                $resultForward = $this->resultForwardFactory->create();
                $resultForward->forward('noroute');
                return $resultForward;
            }



    }


}
```

Below the `di.xml` file code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View" type="Magenticians\AddModule\Controller\Rewrite\Category\View" />
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View" type="Magenticians\AddModule\Controller\Rewrite\Product\View" />
</config>
```

But even when i try with var_dump there is no result can any one tell me the error in my code.

Comment: have you tried after di compile and cache flush your code perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Just check one by one what values you are getting in these 3 values.

```
$this->_request->getParam('___from_store')

  $this->_request->isPost()

  $this->_request->getParam(self::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED)
```

only these conditions are not satisfying that's why below code is running every time in you controller.

```
// Prepare helper and params
        $params = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
        $params->setCategoryId($categoryId);
        $params->setSpecifyOptions($specifyOptions);

        // Render page
        try {
            $page = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
            $this->viewHelper->prepareAndRender($page, $productId, $this, $params);
            return $page;
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            return $this->noProductRedirect();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->_objectManager->get(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::class)->critical($e);
            $resultForward = $this->resultForwardFactory->create();
            $resultForward->forward('noroute');
            return $resultForward;
        }
```

Comment: i want that not loged in customer to  detailed product that  exists in category number (id) 8 will be redirected to login page

Comment: can  you please explain to me the  functionnality of  this if 
                if (!$this->_request->getParam('___from_store')
                    && $this->_request->isPost()
                    && $this->_request->getParam(self::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED))

Answer (score 0):

Create a module and add the below code to your **di.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View">
        <plugin name="vendor_module_product_controller_view" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Catalog\Controller\Product\View" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Create Plugin file like below under:

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/Catalog/Controller/Product/View.php

and add the below content to the file:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Catalog\Controller\Product;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class View
{
    protected $customerSession;
    protected $urlInterface;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlInterface
    ) {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->urlInterface = $urlInterface;
    }

    public function aroundExecute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View $subject,
        \Closure $proceed
    )
    {
        if(!$this->customerSession->isLoggedin())
        {
            $this->customerSession->setAfterAuthUrl($this->urlInterface->getCurrentUrl());
            $this->customerSession->authenticate();
        }
        return $proceed();
    }
}
```

Run set upgrade, di compile and other required commands and test.

Comment: it is my first time with plugin and other question i want that not loged in customer for my specific  category ca't access to detailes page  i see here in your code that you just tested on loged in customer, thanks again to your replay

Comment: What do you exactly want?  Above code redirects the guest customer to login when accessing any product details page.